# How to change rendered template in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a Meteor template in HTML-file:

`<template name='main'>
</template>`

I rendered it using Iron router:

`Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('main');
});`

Now I want to render another template to replace 'main' template. How to do it?

Comment: If this question is about iron:router you should probably tag it as such, to avoid confusion. Do you have more code you can show, it would be less work to answer the question.

Comment: @BjornTipling thank you, I corrected the answer.

Comment: I assume that you want to replace this template as a result of a certain user action. What would that be?

Comment: @apendua click on some element

Comment: So changing route as well or just click?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you do not want another route?

If not you can use a reactive var in the router.  When you change the variable it will run again and render your other template.
See http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/#hooks

```
var OnBeforeActions;

OnBeforeActions = {
    whichMain: function() {
       if (reactiveVar) {
        this.render('otherMain');
      }
       else 
        this.next()  ;
    }
};

Router.onBeforeAction(OnBeforeActions.whichMain, {
    only: ['Main']
});
```

Alternatively use a dynamic template inside your main router.

https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/blaze-dynamic-template-includes/

Comment: Thank you!
Could you show, how to use a reactive var in the router? I think it's that I need, but I don't understand how to implement it.
I do not want another route in this case due to the app logic.

Comment: you're welcome - please look at this: http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/#hooks
Where Meteor.user is the reactive var that makes it rerun.
I don't have time right now to create example - I hope to, have tomorrow.

Comment: thanks!
If I understand correctly, I can make `if (reactiveVar) { this.render(reactiveVar); }`
And every time I assign `reactiveVar='anotherMain'` the page will rerender with _anotherMain_ template, right?

Comment: You would like to make the route name dynamic? (will you be using many differents routes?) I don't know if that works - guess it will!
If that works - you actually don't need the 'if (reactiveVar)' part. See http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/#hooks

Comment: No I don't need many different routes. I need many different templates for the same route. And I need to change them on user click.